# Strange use of "works by"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase *works by* mean here? The structure of the sentence doesn't seem correct to me.

> [Borgarnes water also has a particularly high surface tension, which the brand explains works by "inhibiting evaporation of the volatiles that want to escape quickly —the aromas, the bouquet."](http://www.eater.com/drinks/2015/11/25/9784954/spirits-water-purity-water-sources)

After doing some research I guess that the author wanted to say that a particularly high surface tension gives a special aromas to the gin because of inhibiting evaporation of the volatiles.

Comment: It's poorly written.  Take out "the brand explains" and it's a bit easier to understand.

Comment: It's also bollocks: if it "works by inhibiting evaporation of the volatiles," then it would have no "aromas." It's advertising hyperbole.

Comment: The effect of high surface tension is to slow the evaporation of aromas, what means less "bouquet" when opening the bottle and, once opened, a longer duration of the "volatiles" in the liquid. The expression "works by" introduces the mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing particularly wrong with "works by," however silly it may sound. There are better ways to express the same sentiment; specifically, one could replace "works by" with "is achieved through":

> Borgarnes water also has a particularly high surface tension, which the brand explains **is achieved through** "inhibiting evaporation of the volatiles that want to escape quickly —the aromas, the bouquet."

Let's make it even more readable:

> According to the manufacturer, in addition to [whatever they were bragging about earlier], Borgarnes water has a high surface tension achieved through inhibiting evaporation of the aromas that constitute the bouquet.

Comment: Why use a $10 word when a $1 word will do?

Comment: @ThePhoton: As you can see, the $1 word is causing a bit of confusion in this case. Some problems just won't go away until you throw some money at them.

Answer (score 1):

"by doing something (by + gerund)" describes the way/method something is done.

- I learn English vocabulary and grammar | by reading novels and making notes.

You can say "by +gerund" is a how-indication.

Longman Dictionary, by preposition, no. 2 http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/by_1